# MATLAB Plotting dot in a specific area over a contourfm plot

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I have a contourfm plot on which I want to place a dot. The contourfm plot by itself works fine with no error. But when I try to place a dot at a specific point, it overrides the contourfm plot and just places a dot on a white background without the eqdconic figure and with the latitude and longitude lines squashed together. I am using hold on and I've tried plotting the data first and plotting the dot first, but both produce the same result. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think maybe I should not be using 'plot' as the command.

** The code has been modified to reflect the answer. plotm was used instead of plot. the x and y values for the dot was switched to reflect MATLAB's lat, lon order (instead of lon, lat.)

```
% Eqdconic script    
    % Define figure and axes
    fg1 = figure(1);
    % set(fg1, 'paperposition', [0 0 8.5 8.5]);
    axesm('MapProjection','eqdconic', 'MapParallels', [], 'MapLatLimit',[-80 -60],'MapLonLimit',[190 250]) % 60-70S and 120-160W
    framem on; gridm on; mlabel on; plabel on; hold all;

    % Old code that was incorrect:
         % xValue = find(x(:,1) == 224); % Longitude closest to  136 03.56W
         % yValue = find(y(1,:) == -66.75); % Latitude closest to 66 39.67S
         % plot(xValue,yValue,'b.','MarkerSize',20);  % Plot a black dot

    % Plot dot    
    plotm(-66.75,224,'k.','MarkerSize',20); 

    hold on

    % Plot data
    frame = dataPoint(:,:,k);
    contourfm(y,x,frame, 'LineStyle', 'none');

    % Colorbar
    caxis([0 100]); 
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h,'Percent');

    % Title: Days 1:1258 inclusive. 20100101 to 20130611
    date = datenum(2009, 12, 31) + k; % Convert t into serial numbers
    str = datestr(date, 'mmm yyyy');
    title(str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1

Use `plotm` instead of `plot`.

### 2

Replace this line

```
plot(xValue,yValue,'b.','MarkerSize',20);  % Plot a black dot
```

with

```
plotm(x(xValue,1),y(1,yValue),'b.','MarkerSize',20);  % Plot a black dot
```

Note that `find` returns the index of the found element not its value. However, in your case you can actually pass the actual values

### 3

If you will not use `xValue` and `yValue` later you can remove these lines

```
xValue = find(x(:,1) == 224); % Longitude closest to  136 03.56W
yValue = find(y(1,:) == -66.75); % Latitude closest to 66 39.67S
```

and change the plotting line to

```
plotm(224,-66.75,'b.','MarkerSize',20);  % Plot a black dot
```

### 4

However this will not plot the dot because the latitude and longitude are swapped comparing to the ranges you have mentioned in `axesm` command. But since you use `contourfm(y,x)`, I assume there should be swapped so the plotting line will be

```
plotm(-66.75,224,'b.','MarkerSize',20);  % Plot a black dot
```

### 5

which gives us a blue dot, so we change the color to black by using `'k.'` instead of `'b.'` and we have

```
% Eqdconic script    
    % Define figure and axes
    fg1 = figure(1);
    % set(fg1, 'paperposition', [0 0 8.5 8.5]);
    axesm('MapProjection','eqdconic', 'MapParallels', [], 'MapLatLimit',[-80 -60],'MapLonLimit',[190 250]) % 60-70S and 120-160W
    framem on; gridm on; mlabel on; plabel on; hold all;
    plotm(-66.75,224,'k.','MarkerSize',20);  % Plot a black dot
```

which produces
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. And you're right about not using xValue, yValue. I didn't realize that it wasn't necessary. I was trying to use plotm with the xValue and yValue (I belatedly realized I had lat and long backwards), and it wasn't working. Directly putting in the lat and long worked.